# BQ AuditLogs in StackDriver ::Missing fields in jobCompletedEvent.job.jobStatistics

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-stackdriver

Looking at BigQuery Audit logs in Stackdriver (using PY Client Libraries).. I'm a bit puzzeled why few fields `billingTier`, `totalProcessedBytes`, `totalTablesProcessed` etc. are missing from `protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobStatistics`

It happens with quite few of the Log Entries not just this one..

Thanks for clarification!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are queries/jobs that have hit the [cache](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cached-results). If you turn caching off and test, then you will see all the statistics that you listed.

For example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for clarification! In that case I was expecting `protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobStatistics` (or `serviceData.jobInsertResponse.resource.jobStatistics` to populate with cacheHit True or False field... perhaps Cache configurations are not exposed in Audit Logs (they're only available in actual API req / res?!)

Comment: Good point. Not sure why that's not returned. Maybe one of the Googlers can clarify.